# JavaScript: Better way to sort an array by setting custom index

Tags: javascript, array

I'm trying to create a sorted array based on the below input data:

**Input:**

`[{"title": "100_baz"}, {"title": "01_foo"}, {"title": "05_bar"}]`

```
function indexSort (input) {    
    let output = [];
    input.forEach(value => {    
        if (value.title && value.title.indexOf('_') !== -1) {
            let targetIndex = parseInt (value.title.split('_')[0]);
            let title = value.title.substring(value.title.indexOf('_') + 1, value.title.length); // extract the string next to '_'
            output[targetIndex] = title;
        }    
    })
    console.log(output)
}
```

**Desired Output:**

[image]

I'm able to get the desired output using the above code snippet, however, I'm looking for a better way to achieve this in terms of good practice, or a concise and clear method in ES5 or ES6.

Comment: There is a slight issue with your desired output. It looks like you want a dictionary because you have key value pairs, but you have it surrounded with brackets like an array. Can you clarify the structure of your desired output? Are you looking for an array or a dictionary?

Comment: @SamG Strictly looking for an array in order to retain the order/index. I have updated the desired output now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating my comments on current implementation, Thanks @Mast for pointing out.

1. You have used `let` for `output`, `targetIndex` and `title`. None of
   them never updated. `const` is better suitable here.
2. Usage of `value.title.indexOf('_')` is repeated. you can use variable.
3. You can avoid `substring` usage because you are already did `value.title.split('_')` and you can use index 1 value from result
       array.

Apart from these minor points, `code looks good to me`.

As you asked, Here is alternative ES6 implementation.

1. Use arrow function
2. With `reduce` and using destructure in input function arguments and have the default value for `title`.
3. In reduce function use destucture to get the values from `split` result.

```js
const data = [{"title": "100_baz"}, {"title": "01_foo"}, {"title": "05_bar"}];

const indexSort = data => data.reduce((acc, {title = ''}) => {
  const [num, value] = title.split('_');
  acc[Number(num)] = value;
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(indexSort(data));
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.

Comment: @Mast, Thanks for suggestion. I just updated my thoughts.

Comment: It’s a matter of opinion, but I prefer only using `const` when the intention of the variable is to never change. In this case, it is a coincidence (caused by the chosen implementation) that the variable never got updated, so I would use `let` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is pretty sound. I can't see any improvements that specifically use ES5/ES6 tricks - the spread operator for example will set all of the other keys to `undefined` instead of leaving them empty, which I think is undesired. Further loops would iterate over those `undefined` keys as well.

That said, here are some improvements:

- Use `reduce` to remove the need for a new array and replace the `forEach`
- Store the return value from `split` and use that to replace the `indexOf` (if the delimiter doesn't exist `split` returns an array of length 1) and `substring` calls
- At the moment, the `indexSort` function isn't as [single-purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) as it could be. It has to know that the `input` array contains a `title` key. This can be moved outside to where the function is called making `indexSort` reusable
- The name `indexSort` is a little misleading - I assumed it was going to sort a preexisting array. Perhaps use something like `arrayFromTitles` instead?

Quick snippet showing these changes:

```
function indexSort (input) {
    return input.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
        let split = current.split('_');
        if ( split.length > 1 ) {
            accumulator[parseInt(split[0])] = split[1];
        }
        return accumulator;
    }, []);
}

let titles = [{"title": "100_baz"}, {"title": "01_foo"}, {"title": "05_bar"}];
indexSort(titles.map(x => x.title));
```